# Running queries dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have my Sql query stored as value in one of key attributes in MongoDb database.I am able to fetch the records from the MongoDb database.I want to run the sql query assosciated after retrieving it from there.
The format of record is as follow:

```
     {

                  "Id":2,

                  "Type":"SqlQuery",

                  "Syntax":"select id from table_name where id = pid and optional_id in ('AC','SU')",

                  "ValueSpecifiers":{

                        "id":"request.id"
                  }
 }
```

I am beginner in springboot.It would be very helpful if someone could guide me some resource or in correct direction .I am confused about is it possible to hit queries by setting few filter parameters here like id dynamically as it varies with request object.I want to run it dynamically without extending crud repository.Its just like hitting db by native queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a character like "?" on your recorded query, and then you replace it with your filters. Example:
In the database you save the query like

> select id from table_name where id = pid and optional_id in (?)

And then you retrieve the query to a variable and replace the "?" with the parameters you want to filter. Something like

> varQuery.replace("?", "'AC', 'SU'")

or

> Replace(varQuery, "?", "'AC', 'SU'")

Comment: I want to run it dynamically without extending crud repository.I am more focussed on that one.As sql statements can vary and they are not in structure.